# How to Keep Live Video in pythoncard

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, wxpython, pygtk, pythoncard

I have a PythonCard GUI **Form** with the Image, Signatue filelds. I need to capture the image from the Live stream,

I am trying to inject my live video as a pythoncard component like staticbox or staticArea

Does PythonCard have the inbuilt Video component or any alternate way to get into the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wxPython's MediaCtrl, but I don't think it works very well with streaming media. Instead, I would recommend a 3rd party widget called the MPlayerCtrl which wraps MPlayer. You can get it on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MplayerCtrl/)

Here is a link for the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/MplayerCtrl/) and I also wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/) for it. It should be noted that I didn't try to make it take screenshots. You'll have to do some research into it to find out if that is supported. If MPlayer can do it, than this wrapper should be able to as well.